# Updating NaiveBayes classifier in matlab

Tags: matlab, adaboost

I'm writing a program for online versions of Bagging and AdaBoost algorithms and I'm using matlab's NaiveBayes classifier as the weak learner. Since as online learners they should get data one at a time, I have to update NaiveBayes classifier at each cycle, but it has no methods for it and I have to store all data in an array and call NaiveBayes.fit on hole array every time. Since I have about 4000 data and in real cases there may be many more I was wondering if you could tell me any better ways to do this? (Also if there are any other weak classifiers that I can look into please let me know)

Yours,
Kourosh

Answer (score 0):

You should run AdaBoost+NaiveBayes only on the new samples. The results can then be used to update the values of the previously found results.

You might also want to check out [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29245-boosting-demo/content/boosting_demo/OnlineNaiveBayes.m) version of a seemingly online version of NaiveBayes in MATLAB.